# Asp.net core generic repository pattern with inheritance not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

I have created a generic repository class and interface which will be subclassed for the concrete repositories.

Here is some of my code:

The generic IRepository interface and Repository class:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T Get(long id);
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
}

public class Repostitory<T> : IRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
    {
        protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private DbSet<T> _entities;
        private string errorMessage = string.Empty;

        public Repostitory(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            this._context = context;
            _entities = context.Set<T>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return _entities.AsEnumerable();
        }

        public T Get(long id)
        {
            return _entities.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
        }

        public void Insert(T entity)
        {
            CheckEntityNotNull(entity);
            _entities.Add(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            CheckEntityNotNull(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            CheckEntityNotNull(entity);
            _entities.Remove(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        private void CheckEntityNotNull(T entity)
        {
            if(entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Entity");
            }
        }
    }
```

Inherited Interface and class:

```
public interface IEventsRepository : IRepository<Event>
{

}

public class EventsRepository : Repostitory<Event>
{
    public EventsRepository(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
    {

    }
}
```

At this moment there is no implementation yet in `IEventsRepository` and `EventsRepository`, but there will be once I got this to work.

In `Startup.cs` I have this in the `ConfigureServices` method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repostitory<>));
    services.AddScoped(typeof(IEventsRepository), typeof(EventsRepository));
}
```

And in the controller:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEventsRepository _eventsRepository;

    public AdminController(IEventsRepository eventsRepository)
    {
        _eventsRepository = eventsRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult EventsIndex()
    {
        var model = _eventsRepository.GetAll();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

When building the application I do not get any errors, or even when I open the homepage.

When I open the `EventsIndex` page an internal server error is raised:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'WebsiteProject.Repositories.EventsRepository`1[WebsiteProject.Models.Event]' to type 'WebsiteProject.Repositories.IEventsRepository`1[WebsiteProject.Models.Event]'.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Change your `IRepository` to `public interface IRepository<T>` and implement the `BaseEntity` only on your `Repository` to create it Generic, also When you create a generic you gotta test it like this first e.g: `Repository<Events> _event = new Repository<Events>()`; then try to pull out the methods within? and see it works?

Comment: Please stop using generic / base repositories :/ stop abusing design patterns.

Comment: @Phill I have been looking for the right way to do this for quite a while now. Could you tell me what the correct way would be to approach this?

Comment: @Phill, generic repository will allow to avoid code duplication. Why is that so bad then?

Comment: @kosist - generic repositories do not avoid code duplication, they force implementation detail on domains that do not require or should not have that implementation. Repositories don't remove duplication of code either, especially if they expose IQueryable<T> in which case all you're doing is moving the dbcontext to another file for 0 gain.

Comment: @Phill, but for example if all my entities have `int Id` field, and I'd like to be able to search entity by Id. Then in generic repository I could have one method `public TDomain GetEntity(int Id)` which is reusable for all entities. If I don't have generic repository, then I have to implement for each entity the same method - which means that I have code duplication, isn't it? And there could be Update, Insert, Delete methods also, or even some more specific but common for all entities. How to handle that then please?

Comment: @kosist, no you don't. `context.Load<Product>(id);`. You're writing interfaces and repositories to wrap up what the dbcontext does for you, for 0 benefit. If you later add an entity that does not use int, you're screwed. If you have an entity which would never be loaded, you're screwed. Repositories is probably the most abused and misunderstood pattern in .NET. That sucks :/

Comment: @Phill, could you recommend some resource where I could get explanation of this pattern in such a details? Because I've read a lot of them, most of explanations are simple, some of them include generic repositories, etc. - so where to get "not abused" explanation of it? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @kosist It's difficult to read, but the best resource for understanding repositories IMO is the infamous DDD book. `Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software` - by Eric Evans. It's examples are in Java but easily understood. And makes you think about your relationship between your domain and repositories differently. It's a very valuable book to read.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it. It was quite simple actually.

All I had to do is make `EventsRepository` also implement `IEventsRepository`.

So instead of

```
public class EventsRepository : Repostitory<Event>
{
    public EventsRepository(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
    {

    }
}
```

I changed it to:

```
public class EventsRepository : Repostitory<Event>, IEventsRepository
{
    public EventsRepository(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
    {

    }
}
```